# How to write mysql update query in magento 2 format?

Tags: magento2, database

In **ResourceModel** model I need to execute update query.

> $sql = "UPDATE 2067_ci_sessions SET data='$cisess_data' WHERE id= $id";

instead of writing direct mysql query how can i write update query in magento 2 format?. Thanks in advance for your valuable answer

```
public function clearMlmSession($cisess_data, $cisess_cookie)
{   

    $table = "2067_ci_sessions";
    $bind = ['id' => $cisess_cookie];

    //For user information
    //select query
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $select = $connection->select()->from(
        $table,
        ['data']
    )->where(
        'id = :id'
    )->limit(
        1
    );
    $cisess_data = $connection->fetchRow($select, $bind);
    //$cisess_data = decode_session_data($cisess_data);
    if (empty($cisess_data)) {
        return false;
    }
    //select query


    //Update Data into table
    $sql = "Update " . $table . " Set data = '$cisess_data' where id = '$cisess_cookie'";
    $result = $connection->exec($sql);
    //$result = $connection->exec($sql);

    print_r($result); die("debug");
}
```

In this function select working correctly like that i need write update, i wrote my update query directly. how to write this update query in magento 2 format?

Comment: If your ResourceModel is extending `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb`, why you can't simply use the default `save()` function?

Comment: Am new in magento 2. So i searched  a lot for update but i didnt get what i need.

Comment: So actually you should clarify what tasks you want to perform. I don't think writing query inside resourcemodel is a good idea.

Comment: I edited my question please checkit.  do u undesrtand what i mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK now I get your point. It's legistimate to use update SQL.

According to the [Github belongs to Marius](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule/blob/master/Model/ResourceModel/Author.php), this is the SQL way:

```
$this->getConnection()->update(
    $object->getResource()->getTableName($table),
    $cisess_data,
    ['id = ?' => (int)$cisess_cookie]
);
```

Replace the above code after the comment `//Update Data into table`.

BTW @Piyush, never use Object instance :)

Comment: Please accept my answer too :)

Comment: How to write this query in the form of above format  update eav_attribute_set set attribute_set_name = replace(attribute_set_name, '_src', '') where attribute_set_name LIKE '%_src%';

Answer (score 6):

You can write like

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('employee'); //gives table name with 
 prefix
//Update Data into table
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set emp_salary = 20000 where emp_id = 12";
$connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307351/magento2-write-updated-query-using-connection-zend-format?noredirect=1#comment442669_307351

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();

// select query
$Table = $this->_resources->getTableName('table_name');
$read = "Select * FROM ". $Table;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($read);

// update query
$write = "Update " . $Table . "Set name = 'test'";
$connection->query($write);
```

Comment: how to write update eav_attribute_set set attribute_set_name = replace(attribute_set_name, '_src', '') where attribute_set_name LIKE '%_src%' ? using magento2 zend format

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307351/magento2-write-updated-query-using-connection-zend-format?noredirect=1#comment442669_307351

Answer (score 0):

The proper way:

assuming:

- `$this->resourceConnection` is instance of
  *Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection*
- `$this->connection` is *$resourceConnection->getConnection(ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION)*
- `$cisess_data` = 'THIS_IS_CISESS_DATA'
- `$id` = 42

Build up a special select:

```
        $select = $this->connection->select()
            ->from(
                false,
                ['data' => $cisess_data]
            )
            ->where('id = ?', $id);
```

please note that we did not select any table, we are using columns to pass thru field-value pairs, and using the conditions required to the update

translate above select as update query:

```
        $updateSelect = $this->connection->updateFromSelect(
            $select,
            $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('2067_ci_sessions')
        );
```

this will result the proper UPDATE command as per

`UPDATE 2067_ci_sessions SET data='THIS_IS_CISESS_DATA' WHERE id= 42;`

at this point you already can run the query

```
        $this->connection->query($updateSelect);
```

or if you like one liners:

```
$this->connection->query(
    $this->connection->updateFromSelect(
        $this->connection->select()
            ->from(
                false,
                ['data' => $cisess_data]
            )
            ->where('id = ?', $id),
        $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('2067_ci_sessions')
    )
);
```

and the reason why this is the proper way:

with simple `$this->getConnection()->update()` you cannot join other table to the update. With this way, you can. Just extend original select with join, be sure that you using aliases for all tables (during running `updateFromSelect()` as well) and you are golden

see https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.7-p2/app/code/Magento/Cron/Model/ResourceModel/Schedule.php#L77

Answer (score -1):

> For single record

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('custom_table'); //gives table name with 
 prefix
//Update Data into table
$sql = "Update " . $tableName . "Set qty = '123' where id = '2'";
$connection->query($sql);
```

> For multiple records

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$updateData = [1 => 7, 2 =>15, 3 => 19, 4=>3];
$insertData = [];
foreach($updateData as $id => $qty) {
$insertData[] = ['id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty];
}
try {
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $connection->insertMultiple($this->getTable('custom_table'), $insertData);
    $connection->commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307351/magento2-write-updated-query-using-connection-zend-format?noredirect=1#comment442669_307351

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item as a, cataloginventory_stock_status as b
SET a.qty = 0, a.is_in_stock = 0 ,use_config_manage_stock = 0,
     b.stock_status = 0
WHERE a.product_id IN (603024,603004) AND a.product_id = b.product_id
```