# Magento2 write updated query using connection & Zend format

Tags: magento2, database, sql, zend-framework

I am trying to add below SQL query in the form of Zend format using Magento connection object
Can you please let me know the syntax of how to follow...

```
update eav_attribute_set set attribute_set_name = replace(attribute_set_name, '_src', '') where attribute_set_name LIKE '%_src%';
```

Here is my method

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        try {
            $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
            $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::ATTRIBUTE_SET_TABLE);

           //Add your logic here
             -----------------------------
             -----------------------------

        } catch (\Exception $e){
            $output->writeln("Something went wrong please check and try again");
        }

    }
```

Comment: you want to write you custom query am I right?

Comment: Yes @Jinesh but can we use like Zend format.

Comment: You can write query like this way 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('mytest'); 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (id, name, age, email) VALUES ('', 'Hello World', 88, 'hello@example.com')";
$connection->query($sql);

Comment: update eav_attribute_set set attribute_set_name = replace(attribute_set_name, '_src', '') where attribute_set_name LIKE '%_src%';

Comment: you can check my answer as well as check this link(https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-create-update-query-without-using-model-file/)

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
                $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                $connection = $resource->getConnection();


                //Update Data into table
                $sql = "update eav_attribute_set set attribute_set_name = replace(attribute_set_name, '_src', '') where attribute_set_name LIKE '%_src%';";
                $connection->query($sql);
```

Try another way :-

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller\Updatequery;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    const QUOTE_TABLE = '[TABLE_NAME]';
    private $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
         Context $context,
         ResourceConnection $resourceConnection)
    {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;

        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();

        $data = ["field1"=>3,"field2"=>15]; // you can use as per your requirement

        $id = 1;

        $where = ['entity_id = ?' => (int)$id];

        $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::QUOTE_TABLE);

        $updatedRows=$connection->update($tableName, $data, $where);

        echo "Updated Rows : ".$updatedRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jinesh but can we use same query in the form of zend format in Magento2? i am looking for that. Can u suggest me

Comment: now check my answer.

Comment: Ok but here where I have to add place replace?

Comment: Here $where = ['entity_id = ?' => replace()];